# Uninstall Linux Mint without deleting partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-mint, uninstall

I've got a dual-boot system using Windows 7 and Linux Mint 13.

When I first installed Mint using the regular Mint installer, the installer did not give me the option of partitioning my drive, presumably because my computer already had 4 partitions.

I decided that I wanted to uninstall Mint and opt for Ubuntu instead, but I have no idea how to remove Mint! Every guide I look at tells me to just delete/reformat the Linux partition... But in my case, no separate partition exists.

Answer (score 1):

Linux Mint must have installed in one of your partitions separately from windows. Start Linux Mint and on the terminal run this command: `sudo blkid`

You will need to enter the password. This will show all partitions and their types and labels.

To uninstall Linux mint you will need to boot the computer with a linux liveCD and format the partition with command or some utility like gparted. Alternatively, you may just delete all files from the command line after booting with linux liveCD.

If you want to install Ubuntu, you may just start Ubuntu install CD, choose the partition and select format partition choice. The installer will format it for you!

Comment: I don't think **sudo** is needed. Also **lsblk** might be a nicer option than **blkid** in this case.

Comment: blkid gives partition types and labels also. lsblk gives sizes also but not labels. The OP can use both commands to see detailed information.

Comment: There's also **findmnt**.

Comment: Knowing what finally happened will be useful for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

A option would be to

1. Identify the partition where Linux Mint is installed, usually using something like `sudo fdisk -l`. Now, let's suppose you analyzed the output from the previous command and identified the partition as `/dev/sdu1`.
2. Recreate the filesystem of the partition: `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdu1`.

This way you'll wipe Linux Mint from the partition without deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Linux Mint had somehow automatically installed using Wubi, and so I did an easy uninstall using that.

Mint was located in C:\linuxmint.